# $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb F_p[t] \to \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb F_p[t^p]$ not smooth

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, differential-forms

In [Stack project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01V4) Definition $29.32.13$ of smoothness there is a counter-example of a morphism $f:\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb F_p[t] \to \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb F_p[t^p]$ that is:

- flat
- locally of finite presentation
- the module of differentials is locally free

But f is not smooth.

## Trying to work out the details:

1. flat

Denote $X:=\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb F_p[t^p], Y:=\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb F_p[t]$. So $f:Y \to X$ induces $g: A\to B$ with $A:=\Bbb F_p[t^p], B:=\Bbb F_p[t]$

$\Bbb F_p[t^p]$ is PID as $\Bbb F_p$ is a field, and $B$ is a torsion-free A-module so $B$ is flat A-module, hence $f$ is flat. Is this correct?

2. locally of finite presentation (Solved)

I tried to find a surjection $\Bbb A[t_1,...,t_n] \to B$  with finitely generated kernel but couldn't. I have hard time visualizing what kind of morphisms $A\to B$ can exist.

3. the module of differentials is locally free (solved)

$\Omega_{B|A}$ is generated by elements $(d b)_{b\in B}$, with $d:b\to \Omega_{B|A}, b \to 1\otimes b - b \otimes 1$. But B is commutative so $\Omega_{B|A} = 0$. Does it follow that $\Omega_{Y|X}$ is locally free?.

4. Finally for smoothness, I want to show that the fibers are not equidimensional. Let $x\in X$.

$f^{-1}(x)=B\otimes_A\kappa(x)$.
I couldn't compute residue field $\kappa(x)$ as I couldn't describe exactly elements of X.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Perhaps for 2. you would see it better if you wrote $A=\mathbb F_p [t], B=\mathbb F_p[t^{1/p}]$ ?

Comment: @Max I am thinking of $t\to t^{1/p}$ which is bijective but It doesn't look like a ring homomorphism, and I don't see otherwise

Comment: It's a ring morphism, but not an algebra morphism. Ok let's take a step back : say you have a ring $R$, and an element $x$ to which you want to add a $p$th root : how do you usually do that ?

Comment: Can we just adjoint the p-th root to $R$?: $\Bbb F_p[t,t^{1/p}]\to \Bbb F_p[t^{1/p}]$?

Comment: How do you adjoin said root, in practice ? What is the definition ? How do you add a root to a polynomial ?

Comment: Ok what I wanted to make you say is : if you want to add a $p$th root to $x\in R$, you take $R[X]/(X^p-x)$

Comment: Right! Thank you! I see now what you mean. so the surjection is $\Bbb F_p[t^p,X]/(X^p-t) \to \Bbb F_p[t]$ and the ideal $(X^p-t)$ is finitely generated. So question 2- solved! thank you!

Comment: your answer to 3. is incorrect. The  commutativity of $B$ does not implies that $b\otimes 1=1\otimes b$. In fact , the differential module is generated by dt.

Comment: Right! thank you. I guess $b\otimes 1=1\otimes b$ is false unless the corresponding bilinear form on the universal property of tensor product verifies $\Phi(1,b)=\Phi(b,1)$? Could you please explain why $\Omega_{B|A}$ is generated by $dt$? and how we can then state the same for $\Omega_{Y|X}$? Is it related to $\Omega_{B|A}=I/I^2$ with $I=Ker(A\otimes A \to A)$

Comment: I see now your point @GreginGre, thanks. It remains now to prove that the fibers are not equidimensional to prove it is not smooth